# What's class they use to graph audio spectrum like this?

Tags: android, fft, android-canvas, spectrum

https://lh4.ggpht.com/Z6q1y1F3B0pIzjbLiPx6AlO4B9aimrjcJObvBQb-Kz3ZNu-6F_Cr3BeXGmbvkgUMZA

https://lh6.ggpht.com/ZTm9aLqj-Faaa0G5bqafudhkEPHTSQ3QhzqJc7uQFPdBGPHPx7QXpxDt-BHq9sAMhus

I think they use class in android.graphics.Canvas but not sure. Now i want to graph audio spectrum like in picture?
Someone know What's class they use to graph audio spectrum like this???
Thanks so much!

Comment: I think they've spent a bit of time fo coding their own UI class

Comment: i dont think so. i can use mothod drawBitmap to graph spectrum? what's different between bitmap and curve?

Comment: Do you need to draw a bitmap from a specific source (from internet or file system) or do you need to draw every single line?

Comment: I need to draw evey single line like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/9bmv2xenpp53bww/screenshot-1363876075257.png

Comment: I think everything you need is in the android.graphic

Comment: Thank you so much. I know what i need to do now. Have a nice day friend :)

Comment: May I know your decision?

Answer (score 0):

The namespace android.Graphics provide base object to build up your own graphic. You need to draw the background, lines, text and try to get something like you want.

The Canva object has several methods:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

For example you cans draw lines using:

canvas.drawLine(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY, Paint paint).

The Paint object is used to have a specific line color/width...

Comment: I understand what you mean but i ask only about curve on that graphs. I know build up background, lines, text but about curve of spectrum?? What's class i can use to do this?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Lines are ok, just build up a **path** and **canvas.drawPath(...)**

Comment: It's called smooth line? Are u sure? I see it before but not sure :(

Comment: For smoother curve you can use Bezier line. I coded my own method: **void drawBeizer(Canvas canvas, Point[] points)** A little complicated...

Comment: where i can find class drawBeizer? Can not find on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Comment: I suggest also to refine your question and explain better what your are exactly looking for.

Comment: I wrote drawBezier because Android does not provide such method

Comment: You mean Bezier is in other language?